# Search SQLite data from user input

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect('ProcessPower.db')

c = conn.cursor()
user_input = (input("Enter a Type: "))

c.execute("SELECT * FROM Instrumentation WHERE Type = ?", user_input)
rows = c.fetchall()
for row in rows:
    print(row)
conn.close()
```

Comment: What you're looking for is called "parameter substitution". You can find some information on it in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/sqlite3.html), as well as in any number of tutorials.

Comment: It works but for a single digit. P is fine but PT it doesn't: ncorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 1, and there are 2 supplied

Comment: FYI: You lost the explanation of the problem when you edited the question. Be sure all the information needed to understand the problem (what you're trying to do, what's happening instead, etc.) is in the body of the question. Comments should be considered temporary. See the possible duplicate target for the solution to your new problem.

Comment: glidud Thanks a million ! It works ;-)

Comment: changed user_input for [user_input]